# How to improve performance: database or text file?

Tags: android, database, performance

My Android app is a client that fetchs datas from a Web Service and show them to the user. I would like to know how to improve performance and avoid continuos connections.

Everytime I click the botton "show" for example I make the connection and get the json string. I know that my string will not change during the day (hopefully).

It's better to get the json string and save it in a text file, save the string on a DB (with "date" and "string" columns for example) and then deserialize it, or directly deserialize the string and save as proper objects in the DB?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a little string, say under 1K, put it in [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).  Otherwise, if your data is going to remain relevant for a few days, use a database.  If your data is going to be pretty much thrown out and refreshed completely each day, and is a few KB, write it in a cache file.

Comment: It's about 12K (10.000 chars more or less).. Everyday I have a new json string of the same lenght. Cache file?

Comment: It's a judgment call, naturally.  I would guess that deserializing objects isn't much better than parsing a file in the first place, and hopefully the time to parse 12k won't be too bothersome to the user.  If it is, your database strategy would work.  Slower overall, but user-perceptible latency will be improved.  In that case, I would just store the strings, not serialized objects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both and then I'll see. : )